# How to make sure console doesn't close immediately when running code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, console

I'm trying to learn C programming, but when I run my code the cmd, window closes immediately, without giving me the change to see if the program printed the result I was aiming for.

I'm coding C on VS-Code, using several extensions. Is there a setting/extension/code snippet, or anything I can do so it won't close immediately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest (and most common) way to do this is to add the line `system("pause");` immediately before the `return 0;` statement in your `main` function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // This header defines the "system()" function
                    // For C++ builds, #include <iostream> will suffice

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This call will produce a prompt and await a key-press from the user. The exact message displayed may vary between compilers and/or platforms but, with Visual Studio and `MSVC`, the message is:

> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I'm curios as to why, assuming this is for the end-user and not debugging (in which case I agree configure your IDE properly), keeping the terminal window open for the average windows user (who doesnt want to/is scared of using a terminal) makes perfect sense and this is a way to do that

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 End users run terminal applications *in the terminal*. It obviously stays open. Having to press a key *in addition* isn’t merely disruptive, it breaks non-interactive workflows.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Typical windows user will see an executable and double click to run it, they will not like the fact that to use your application they have too go into cmd or powershell. I agree for people on mac and linux (me) it makes sense to run it from the terminal but I know many windows programs which are patchers or whatever which you expect (as a windows user) to double click and then hit a key to exit once its done

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph This is still used by many single-use or fire and forget windows applications though, the OP wanted to know how to keep a terminal window open, this and may of the other answers here are ways of doing that which the OP may find useful for just such an application, whether it is good design or not is debatable and is dependent on use case.

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 When arguing that something “is used by many”, remember Sturgeon’s Law: “ ninety percent of everything is crap”. Do many (bad) applications use this? Yes. Is it ever a good idea? Unambiguously no. It’s always a crutch, and a bad one at that. There’s simply no debate about this amongst experienced programmers. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getchar ()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World! (presse enter to leave)\n");
    getchar (); //<-- presse enter to leave
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Same as the other answers, this is a bad crutch. Configure your IDE properly instead of messing up the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd feature of Visual Studio.

If you run a console application without debugging (ctrl-F5) then Visual Studio automatically holds the console open for you when the program terminates.

It does not do this when you run in the debugger (F5)  - the expectation being that you can hold the process open for yourself with a breakpoint somewhere.

Comment: The question is about [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), not [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) (which are two completely different products, both made by Microsoft).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The question was tagged Visual Studio until you changed it.

Comment: Yes, but the question was also tagged `visual-studio-code` from the start and the text of the question explicity stated "VS-Code" from the start. Therefore, I believe it can be safely assumed that the question was incorrectly tagged as `visual-studio`. I wish Microsoft would name its products in a less confusing manner.

Answer (score 0):

In `C++` it can be as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit.\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

In `C`, I would go with Landstalker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60811750/10732434).

Or set a breakpoint (`F9` on default) at the last statement (`return 0;`), then continue (`F5` on default) when you want to exit your program.

Comment: @Landstalker It is tagged with `c++`. Don't ask me why.

Comment: @sanitizedUser it is tagged C and C++

Comment: Same as the other answer, this is a bad crutch. Configure your IDE properly instead of messing up the code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I offered a IDE setting solution (breakpoints).

Comment: @sanitizedUser That’s also just a crutch. There must be another setting. I’m not using Windows so I don’t know *which* one, but on macOS, when running code in VS Code the terminal window stays open, as it should.

Comment: I marked it as C++ as well because I was trying to fill the 5 tags allowed, thought people who know it might know a little C too! :D
Is that bad to tag stuff like that? as you can see I'm new here 

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'm making a quick answer. VS didn't use to stay open when a program was finished. You had to use `system.("PAUSE");` to keep it open. But, VS changed that so once the main function returns, it halts the command prompt for you. Most IDEs don't work this way, and running outside of an IDE will not work this way, without some added intervention in your code, like `system.("PAUSE");`.