# The destructor message is not appearing on the console C++

Tags: c++, destructor

So after I run my code the console -in visual studio- disappears too fast before I click any button so I started to use `cin.get();` or `cin.ignore();` to solve this problem.

And because of that I can't see a `cout` message on the console which is my destrcutor function. Only when I delete the `cin.get();` function I'm able then to see the message but it desapears too fast.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make sure console doesn't close immediately when running code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811419/how-to-make-sure-console-doesnt-close-immediately-when-running-code)

Comment: @AdrianMole This is not what OP was asking. OP wants to display a (test) message from a destructor before the pause.

Comment: @Danny_ds Not sure about that - OP says they can see the message but then the console closes, and adding `system("pause")` could delay the disappearance?

Comment: @AdrianMole The problem in this case is that the destructor would be called after the pause (the message is displayed in the destructor).

Comment: @Danny_ds Yeah - I see what you mean! (If the d'tor is *only* called when the program's `main` exits.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the code between curly braces to force a call of the destructor:

```
int main()
{
    {
        YourVar test;

    } // destructor of test is called

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Or even better as Remy Lebeau suggests in the comment:

```
void doIt()
{
    YourVar test;

} // destructor of test is called

int main()
{
    doIt();

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or, just move your code to a separate function: `void doIt() { YourVar test; ... } int main() { doIt(); cin.get(); return 0; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would even be better. Added in the answer.